# Is there any easier way of setting up the array from a mysqli result set

Tags: php, mysqli

Does any body know an easier way of setting of this contacts array from a results set from mysqli??  Also does anyone have any good mysqli insert php functions (procedural) that is easy to debug if the sql query has a syntax error in it?

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT id, name, contactNo, email, address, county, country, sourceOfContact, type FROM contacts');

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$contacts[] = array('id' => $row['id'],
                    'name' => $row['name'],
                    'contactNo' => $row['contactNo'],
                    'email' => $row['email'],
                    'address' => $row['address'],
                    'county' => $row['county'],
                    'country' => $row['country'],
                    'sourceOfContact' => $row['sourceOfContact'],
                    'type' => $row['type']

}
```

Comment: `$contacts[] = $row;` ??

Comment: You are assigning every element of the array into an identically named element of another array... Think this through for a second...

Answer (score 4):

Simply read the appropriate PHP manual pages and

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT id, name, contactNo, email, address, county, country, sourceOfContact, type FROM contacts');

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $contacts[] = $row;
}
```

.... amazing what you can read in the manual if you look

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT id, name, contactNo, email, address, county, country, sourceOfContact, type FROM contacts');

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{ 
$contacts[] = $row;
}
```

is much better and you get the same result.

Also, regarding your question, just create a wrapper function and always use that such as db_mysqli_query(...) which automatically does the error handling of a query however you wish. Just remember to call your query function instead of the built in mysql query function when you want to make a query.

P.S. You're question was a little hard to understand and is a bit of a too broad question to ask. But i did my best to answer it anyway.